# how to load jade file in node.js after making Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

In my node.js application i am making an Ajax class on a button click and i want to load the new html file. Everything is happening great but the new html file is not getting loaded.

I am making ajax call like this in main.jade file:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".login-button").click(function() {
                  $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:3000/admin",
                    data: { name: "xyz", organization: "abcdz" }
                  })

router.post('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('summary', { name: req.body.name})
});
```

After making ajax call on click of login button i want to load summary.jade file but it's not getting loaded instead its showing login page.

I am not getting the idea how to do this.

> app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

Comment: `res.render` sends out html. If you need that, you have to attach an `onSuccess` handler for your post and inject the content into the dom

Answer (score 0):

[res.render](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) sends out html. If you need the html to be rendered, you have to attach an success handler for your `post` and inject the content into the dom.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/admin",
        data: { name: "xyz", organization: "abcdz" }
        success: function (data) {
        //data is the resultant html when gets created by res.render()
       // wanna show it, add it to the dom
       $('.some-element').html(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: ok... but this one is like in same html page i should have some-element class but my requirement is i want to load another page.. I dont want to show on the same page.

Comment: In that case, instead of `res.render('summary', { name: req.body.name})`, do a `res.redirect` to the route. http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.redirect

Comment: I tried res.redirect but this is also not working for me

Comment: router.post('/admin', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('www.google.com'); 
});
Does this work?

Comment: No this is also not working... In the log the request is getting send and response is also coming but on browser page is not getting changed